# Add file list, delete and download in ESP32 simple file server

Tags: c++, esp32, arduino-esp32

It's the first time to ask a question, please forgive me if I am wrong.
English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.
I am using ESP32 for the first time. I want to be a file server, but now it only has upload function. I want to add download, delete and file list. I have not been able to find suitable information. thank you.
ESP32 code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <AsyncTCP.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SPIFFS.h>

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  if(!SPIFFS.begin()){
          Serial.println("An Error has occurred while mounting SPIFFS");
  }

  start_access_point();
  start_web_server();
}

void loop()
{
  
}

const char* ap_ssid = "ESP32";
const char* ap_pwd = "12345678";

void start_access_point(){
  WiFi.softAP(ap_ssid, ap_pwd);
  IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();  
  Serial.println("Access point started");
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(myIP);
}

AsyncWebServer server(80);

const char* PARAM_SSID = "ssid";
const char* PARAM_PWD = "pwd";

void start_web_server(){
  
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
      request->send(SPIFFS, "/index.html", "text/html");
  });


  server.on("/upload", HTTP_POST, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    if(request->hasArg("file")){
      String fileName = request->arg("file");
      File f = SPIFFS.open("/data/fileName", "w");
      if(!f){
        request->send(500, "text/plain", "Could not open file for writing");
        return;
      }
      std::string fileData = std::string(request->arg("file").c_str());
      f.write((uint8_t*)fileData.c_str(), fileData.length());
      f.close();
      request->send(200, "text/plain", "File uploaded successfully");
    }
    else{
      request->send(500, "text/plain", "No file data found in request");
    }
  });
  server.begin();
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <style>.app-container{
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}

h3{
    text-align: center;
    color: #5a5c69 !important;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* Style inputs, select elements and textareas */
input[type=text], select, textarea{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    resize: vertical;
  }

input[type=password], select, textarea{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    resize: vertical;
  }
  
  /* Style the label to display next to the inputs */
  label {
    padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  /* Style the submit button */
  input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
  }
  
  /* Floating column for labels: 25% width */
.col-25 {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    margin-top: 6px;
  }
  
  /* Floating column for inputs: 75% width */
  .col-75 {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    margin-top: 6px;
  }
  
  /* Clear floats after the columns */
  .row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  
  /* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 600px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .col-25, .col-75, input[type=submit] {
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 0;
    }
  }
    </style>
    <title id="apptitle">Setup Wifi</title>
<head>
    <title>File Upload</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>File Upload</h1>
    <form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file" />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
    <a href="/download/fileName">Download file</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to find a similar function modification on github, but there was no way

Answer (score 0):

List. Simple iteration through all files in the data folder of esp32. Absolute path deletion before file name has to be done manually if you just want the file names:

```cpp
#include "SPIFFS.h"
 
void setup() {
 
  Serial.begin(115200);
 
  if (!SPIFFS.begin(true)) {
    Serial.println("An Error has occurred while mounting SPIFFS");
    return;
  }
 
  File root = SPIFFS.open("/");
 
  File file = root.openNextFile();
 
  while(file){
 
      Serial.print("FILE: ");
      Serial.println(file.name());
 
      file = root.openNextFile();
  }
}
 
void loop() {}
```

Delete:

```cpp
SPIFFS.remove(path); (all paths are absolute paths)
```

exists function to check if file exists 
mkdir creating new folder
rmdir remove folder
opendir
rename
info
and more can be found here. just scroll down enough until you find them in the documentation:
https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filesystem.html

Edit: Forgot to add download here. Download can be accomplished similarly to what you already have for your API:

```cpp
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
      request->send(SPIFFS, "/index.html", "text/html");
  });
```

It could send you to a new tab with the new link and use the response as a download buffer type thing. But change the type to the type of file you want. Im not quite sure what the name of the type was but i think it was something on the line of "binary/png" or something. you'd have to search that up